# Marshalling DWORD in C# as long or int?

Tags: c#, struct, pinvoke, dword

I am P-Invoking [SetServiceStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686241(v=vs.85).aspx) in my C# application. Microsoft's implementation dictates the [DWORD components of SERVICE_STATUS struct are Marshalled as long (Int64) rather than int.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer)

I understand that these need to be unsigned (but the CLS does not allow unsigned types), so I was wondering whether the reason that Microsoft is suggesting using long rather than int to circumvent the unsigned CLS issue?

Also, the thing that's nagging me that DWORD is 32 bit and long(C#) is 64 bit, but the example from Microsoft says that the struct is to be declared as sequential layout, so I do not understand how this is working (confirmed working on my machine)

Comment: Yeah, that is nonsense.  The entire section is bogus, the ServiceBase class already does this.  And has the rookie mistake of not checking the return value of SetServiceStatus().  Two reasons why they never saw the bug.

Comment: I see int on Microsoft's implementation on the link. Has the Microsoft updated?

Answer (score 1):

That article is wrong. Those fields should be `uint` or perhals `int` depending on your preferences. As you correctly point out `long` in C# is a 64 bit type.

Comment: How do you explain it still working with 64 bit fields though?

Comment: It isn't working. The wrong values will land in the unmanaged code. There may be a coincidence that it seems to be write, for instance is zeros are passed for all fields.

Comment: That's what i am afraid as well. It might look like it's working..but it's not. Just wanted to confirm my hunch.

What's weird is that PInvoke.Net says the same sadly.http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures.SetServiceStatus

Answer (score -1):

I guess I was right; I've changed all the long to uint and all went fine.

The enum and struct should look as follows.

```
public enum ServiceState
{
SERVICE_STOPPED = 0x00000001,
SERVICE_START_PENDING = 0x00000002,
SERVICE_STOP_PENDING = 0x00000003,
SERVICE_RUNNING = 0x00000004,
SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING = 0x00000005,
SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING = 0x00000006,
SERVICE_PAUSED = 0x00000007,
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ServiceStatus
{
public uint dwServiceType;
public ServiceState dwCurrentState;
public uint dwControlsAccepted;
public uint dwWin32ExitCode;
public uint dwServiceSpecificExitCode;
public uint dwCheckPoint;
public uint dwWaitHint;
};
```

I've also written a quick blog post about it.

https://albertherd.com/2017/10/19/code-never-lies-documentation-sometimes-do/